# question about decomposition of positive terms series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_k$ where $a_k=b_k + c_k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_k$ be a series at positive terms. and with some positive free parameter x.

now suppose  $a_k=b_k + c_k$ for all k. what can we say in general about the series by looking at $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_k(x)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_k$.

does it converge if and only if both of them converge? or in general we can't really say anything about such a series?

to give context if I may wasn't clear here's an example of what i mean:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^x+1}{\log(n)}, \quad x>0\tag{i}$$

notice:

$$\frac{n^x+1}{\log(n)}=\frac{n^x}{\log(n)} +\frac{1}{\log(n)}$$

then we can assure that the terms where (i) converges are the same where both of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^x}{\log(n)}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\log(n)}$ converge? and those where (i) diverges are the same where at least 1 of the former 2 diverge?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\tag{1}$$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\tag{2}$$ converge, then it is very easy to show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(b_n + c_n)\tag{3}$$ converges.

The converse is not always true, as the example $b_n=-n, c_n=n$ shows.

---

The converse can be true under some additional conditions though. For example, if $b_n$ and $c_n$ are all positive, then we can prove that if the sum $(3)$ converges, then the sum $(1)$ also converges.

You can prove this easily because you have $|b_n| = b_n \leq b_n + c_n$. Knowing this, [the comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) immediately gives the result that $(1)$ is a convergent sum.

Comment: thank you, you are right about that counterxample.  But can it happen something like that if the terms are all positives?  intuitively I wold say no, since correct me if I am wrong, but in that case the series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: @invictus If all terms are positive, then $b_n < b_n + c_n = a_n$ and you have guaranteed convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$ if $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ converges.

Comment: thank you again for the help, I have one last doubt though, assume again that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ has all positive terms, but this time it diverges. Can we be certain that at least one of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$  or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n$ must diverge?     (Again $b_n,c_n$ are all positive terms)

Comment: @invictus Well, if sums $(1)$ and $(2)$ converge, then $(3)$ also converges. And you should also know that $p\implies q$ is the same as $\neg q\implies \neg p$.

Comment: lol, sorry didn't notice it was just the contrapositive of the claim. anyway thanks for your time

Comment: @invictus Sometimes the answer is so simple you miss it, it happens :)